# MySQLi Insert Into If

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The issue I am having is the PHP code below only inserts the data into one table blue. What I want is if the directory category from the POST is equal to for example blue INSERT into Table blue , but if it is equal to yellow INSERT into yellow, but if it's equal to red INSERT into table red.

The only answers I have found deal with insert if exist but not multiple insert if statements. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am just learning PHP code.

```
    <?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','some directory','password','some username');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//values to be inserted in database table
$firstname  = '$_POST[firstname]'; 
$lastname   = '$_POST[lastname]';
$city       = '$_POST[city]';   
$state      = '$_POST[state]';
$zipcode    = '$_POST[zipcode]';
$directorycategory  = '$_POST[directorycategory]';
$active     = '$_POST[active]';


    $query = ("INSERT INTO blue(
            firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    //bind parameters
    $statement->bind_param('sssssss', $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['zipcode'], $_POST['directorycategory'], $_POST['active']);

    if($statement->execute()){
       header("some location");
    }else{
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
    }
    $statement->close();
?>
```

Comment: firstly, start by removing the quotes for `'$_POST[firstname]'` and all others and use the quotes themselves inside the array name itself. i.e. `$_POST['firstname']` - you have those quotes in the wrong pegs. However, you don't need those, you already have them in the binds and properly formatted, so why are they in your code?

Comment: You can concatenate the value of `$_POST['directorycategory']` to your query string `$query = ("INSERT INTO " . $_POST['directorycategory'] . "(firstname, lastname, city, st ...");`

Comment: @PLAudet Better sanitize that input first, though.

Comment: Well I just gave him the solution. Can't make all the work for him ;-). Also, he didn't sanitize anything so... (but I agree with  you)

Comment: a case switch would work too. many ways to go about this, even through SQL.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang with sanitize you mean just put the variables inside  `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @PHPeter Yes, first & foremost -- and I'd be inclined to use `htmlspecialchars()` as well, on the off chance that it'd be rendered on the page later, to avoid XSS.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang I thought I didn't have to sanitize the input when using prepared statements. Is that still correct?

Comment: Geez, that could be a whole other question. In short: I usually use PDO rather than mysqli, but I *assume* the `bind_param` would effectively do what `mysqli_real_escape_string()` does. As for protecting from XSS, though, these methods won't protect you: they're designed to avoid SQL injection, whereas XSS involves a different means of attack. That's why I mentioned the `htmlspecialchars()` function: that's designed to protect against XSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@oremIpsum1771 Your answer works the best. The final code is as follows

```
     <?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','some directory','password','some username');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//values to be inserted in database table
$firstname  = '$_POST[firstname]'; 
$lastname   = '$_POST[lastname]';
$city       = '$_POST[city]';   
$state      = '$_POST[state]';
$zipcode    = '$_POST[zipcode]';
$directorycategory  = '$_POST[directorycategory]';
$active     = '$_POST[active]';


        if($directorycategory  == 'Employer'){
    $query = ("INSERT INTO employer(
            firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        }
     else if($directorycategory  == 'Blue'){$query = ("INSERT INTO blue(
        firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); }
     else if($directorycategory  == 'Green'){$query = ("INSERT INTO green(
        firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); }
     else if($directorycategory  == 'Red'){$query = ("INSERT INTO red(
        firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); }
     else if($directorycategory  == 'Orange'){$query = ("INSERT INTO orange(
        firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); }       

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    //bind parameters
    $statement->bind_param('sssssss', $firstname, $lastname, $city, $state, $zipcode, $directorycategory, $active);

    if($statement->execute()){
       header("some location");
    }else{
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
    }
    $statement->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, you can mark it as the answer for future visitors of this page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing where you have the control structure for the query. If i'm understanding the problem correctly, I would think that you would need something like this:

```
    if(directorycategory  == 'blue'){$query = ("INSERT INTO blue(
        firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); }           
    else if(directorycategory  == 'yellow'){$query = ("INSERT INTO yellow(
        firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); }
```

etc....

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = ("INSERT INTO ".$_POST['directorycategory']."(
        firstname, lastname, city, state, zipcode, directorycategory, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

You can use the period to concatenate strings with variables to make 1 big string.

Comment: @champlow007 For some reason I get a blank page when using that query. Is that the only command I need to change in my code? The value of directory category comes from a select box in an html form.

Comment: Does it work when you try to do something simple like 

$query = ("INSERT INTO blue(firstname) VALUES (?)");

$statement->bind_param('s', 'Marquise');

Comment: @champlow007  yes that works. I have four tables in MySQL. I have an html form it has a drop down menu, if a user selects blue I want the insert to insert all the data from the POST into the selected MySQL table that was selected on the form.